# SQLite Add counter from row to next row

Tags: sqlite, row, addition, counter

I have the following table:

```
Table final
-id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
-addcounter TEXT NOT NULL
-secondaryID TEXT NOT NULL
```

With the following format:

```
1   0   1
2   1   null
3   1   null
4   0   null
5   0   null
```

So basically, on (secondaryID for row X) = (secondaryID for row X-1) + (addcounter for row X-1)

So the table above should result in:

```
1   0   1
2   1   1
3   1   2
4   0   3
5   0   3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE final
SET secondaryID = (SELECT secondaryID
                   FROM final
                   ORDER BY id
                   LIMIT 1) +
                  (SELECT SUM(addcounter)
                   FROM final AS f2
                   WHERE id < final.id)
WHERE secondaryID IS NULL
```